# Are Kernel modules independent of the underlying hardware architecture

Tags: linux, kernel-module

For example,
if I have a hello_world kernel module on Ubuntu running on Intel x86 platform. Would I be able to take that hello_world kernel module and execute on Ubuntu running on AMD platform without modifying the kernel module.

Comment: kernel module is built against a particular kernel. if you can run the same kernel in AMD platform, then yes, you should be able to load the module as well.

Comment: @iamauser: You are better post your comment as an answer, because it actually answers the question.